# Convert SqlDataReader into array

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

C# code :

```
string conn = @"Data Source=MRT\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=hrm;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*******";

SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
objsqlconn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_fetchtest", objsqlconn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter lastname = cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Int);
lastname.Value = 6;

SqlDataReader sdr;
sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Stored procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_fetchtest] 
    @userid int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT firstName, lastName 
    FROM personal  
    WHERE personal.userid = @userid
END
```

How can I store this value in two array for firstname and lastname? So I can operate on that info in further project steps?

Comment: What have you tried? And what exactly do you mean by "...in two array". It all depends on how you want to access the data later. What kind of requirements you have...

Comment: i want to use that value for create pdf using iTextSharp.

Comment: can you help me @barns ?

Comment: Looks like you found your answer. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for giving your valuable time @Barns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the Read method:

```
while(sdr.Read())
{
    //Use get methods ex. sdr.GetString(columnIndex) or indexer sdr["firstName"] to 
    //extract data and place them in to other objects for further processing.
}
```